# How is HTTP Host Availability in flutter 2.10?

Tags: flutter

When I run `flutter doctor -v` in Flutter stable version 2.10.1, I get this check:

```
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    ✗ HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error
      occurred while checking the HTTP host: Operation timed out
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution works https://blog.csdn.net/ouhuanquan/article/details/123134340

1. Open ${FLUTTER_HOME}\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\http_host_validator.dart
2. Change `https://maven.google.com/` to `https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/`
3. Close Terminal
4. Open ${FLUTTER_HOME}\bin and delete cache directory
5. Reopen Terminal and exec `flutter doctor`

Comment: It's work for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution works

go to {FLUTTER_HOME}\packages\flutter_tools\lib\src\http_host_validator.dart

Change https://maven.google.com/ to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/

save and close

Open {FLUTTER_HOME}\bin

delete cache directory

then run flutter doctor