# When I run flutter doctor in Flutter stable version 2.10.1, I get this check: How do I resolve this?

Tags: flutter

`[!] HTTP Host Availability X HTTP host https://cloud.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: The semaphore timeout period has expired.`

How do I resolve this?

For reference I also had  `✗ HTTP host https://maven.google.com/ is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Operation timed out` and this was the solution to that [How is HTTP Host Availability in flutter 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063780/how-is-http-host-availability-in-flutter-2-10)

Comment: Seems you're not connected to the internet. If you're, try a VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Experienced the same issue, for me it was BitDefender's firewall not allowing Dart.exe the permissions it needed.

Try the following:

- Disable Antivirus or some defender software
- Allow firewall permissions

Comment: McAfee's firewall caused the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error, I resolved this using  SDK manager...

On your dashboard, go to Tools, click SDK manager, then click on Android SDK, on the right hand side, you would see SDK Update sites, click on it and at the bottom of the page, click on the force and the disable buttons.

This should do the trick.

[How to find SDK manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wIMN.png)

[The force and Disable buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhLcA.png)