# https://pub.dev/ https://cloud.google.com/ not reachable doctor && Error: A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'T'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

All of a sudden this error message popped up

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:307:9: Error: 'ntthrow' isn't a type.
ntthrow ProviderNullException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:307:17: Error: Expected ';' after this.
ntthrow ProviderNullException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:307:40: Error: Expected ')' before this.
ntthrow ProviderNullException(T, context.widget.runtimeType);
^

/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-6.0.4/lib/src/provider.dart:309:14: Error: A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'T' because 'T?' is nullable and 'T' isn't.
return value;

It appeared when I added this line :
**import 'package:provider/provider.dart';**

*pubspec.yaml :*

**environment:** sdk: '>=2.18.2 <3.0.0'

**dependencies:** provider: ^6.0.4

By making flutter doctor, I get this : [[SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71341459/17526926) (for doctor message not the one below)

[image]

What can I do ?

Comment: `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. also Check if you are providing  ProviderType. and  try https://stackoverflow.com/q/71620085/10157127

Comment: The errors given by flutter doctor are gone by following the info in your link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71063780/how-is-http-host-availability-in-flutter-2-10
I checked all ProviderType, it seems ok But I still have the red message error with the Provider thing and gradle 
The Provider error happened after disconnecting and reconnecting the mobile device to the PC

Comment: Can you include sample code how you are calling provider

Comment: Please do not use images of error messages. Paste the actual error messages.

Answer (score 0):

flutter clean followed by flutter pub get. also would recommend to recheck your internet connection, close and reopen your IDE and rerun flutter doctor

Comment: I did flutter clean & flutter pub get without result

The Provider error happened after disconnecting and reconnecting the mobile device to the PC

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I changed this on Pubspec.yaml
**provider: ^5.0.0-nullsafety.2**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was connected with a VPN so this error was coming I disconnected VPN and it's working fine now.

Answer (score -2):

I was connected to the internet without VPN and had this problem, but when I connected with VPN, the problem was solved. If you are connected to the Internet from a place that is sanctioned by the US, you must connect with a VPN to solve the problem.